Upgrade to 23.10 - libgd3
I know I'm a bit late to the party but I'm currently on 23.04 and are wanting to upgrade to 23.10.
Running apt upgrade reveals The following packages have been kept back: libgd3 and halts there. When running apt-get install libgd3 I get libgd3 : Depends: libavif13 (>= 0.9.3) but it is not installable Depends: libtiff5 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not installable
I could of course remove it but am told that the following will be removed colord gnome-control-center gvfs-backends hplip libc-devtools libgd3 libgphoto2-6 libm17n-0 libsane1 php8.2-gd sane-utils shotwell simple-scan ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal which includes ubuntu-desktop which as a desktop user is critical to me!?
Does 23.10 use this file? Is there any workaround? I don't know if I installed the file or if it came with a repo but I've tried to keep my install options quite limited rather than just installing anything.
This does not relate to older software but rather a package which simply cannot be upgraded. I need to know if removing ubuntu-desktop will (as I assume) break my Desktop from working.

"This does not relate to older software" ... It does - you're on 23.04 which is currently obsolete and unsupported, and has unmaintained repositories and mirrors, which is likely the reason for your error. And that is addressed in the duplicate.

Actually for anyone else finding this - a better answer is here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1491832/23-04-23-10-release-upgrade-dependent-on-held-back-packages and for me removing the PHP PPA (from a comment) was the solution.
